# How do I get around SafeConnect for devices that don't support it?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, laptop

I just moved into my college dorm and their Internet is very limiting. All we have access to is WiFi, and we must install something call Safeconnect that monitors the computer and network connections.

This rules out anything other than a Mac/PC connecting easily. I have my laptop which is connected. I brought a network hub assuming I'd have access to an ethernet port and could spread that network to my Smart TV and Xbox 360 and such. I get locked out if I "share" the network connection. It basically senses the ICS service and locks all connections out.

Ideally I'd like an ethernet cable running from my laptop to the hub, and then connections running to both the TV and Xbox 360. On the TV I have access to all the IP settings. Is what I want to do possible?

Comment: Looks like you're either ending up getting a MiFi or risking getting expelled, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will work as I havent tried it before... However, you could try installing a virtual machine with shared networking (not bridged) on your laptop.  Then add a wired/wireless USB adapter the laptop, but dedicate it to the VM.   Then install and run ICS off the virtual machines mapped adapter.

Network administrators at universities/colleges are not dumb.  They know students are going to try and bypass their network restrictions.  They have plenty of safeguards and monitoring to detect and combat students trying to break the rules.

Im not saying you shouldnt do it, but you need to think of what the consequences are if you get caught breaking the rules.  Mom and Dad wont be to happy with a student who gets kicked out of school, or is put on some kind of probation.

Comment: Keltari, do you think I can do that directly through the Ethernet port to the hub, or do I definitely need usb?

Comment: wait, i just reread your post.  I got it backwards.  You will be receiving your IP through wireless, so you want to bind the wired to the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I am in an identical situation.  I downloaded connectify, installed it on my windows 7 pc, and am using that.  Connectify turns creates a wifi hotspot from your computer.  Also if you go to your school's IT department, sometimes they can enter something called a MAC address (no relation to a certain fruit company that sells computers) and allow you to get on the network without safeconnect.